# PostgreSQL - Count after filtering conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these columns on my table:

```
id       country     
A        Italy
A        France
A        Germany
B        Italy
B        France
C        Italy
C        France
```

I want to get ***id*** with contains ***ONLY*** Italy and France, so the result will becoming like this:

```
id  
B
C
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this for me is to just aggregate by the `id` and then assert that the minimum country is France, and the maximum Italy:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(country) = 'France' AND MAX(country) = 'Italy' AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT country) = 2;
```

Comment: @Nick No, you're wrong, and my (current) answer has no such caviats.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using `exists`

```
     with cte as
(
select 'A' as id , 'Italy' as country union all
select 'A','France' union all
select 'A','Germany' union all
select 'B','Italy' union all
select 'B','France' union all
select 'C' ,'Italy' union all
select 'C','France' 

) select distinct id from cte t1
 where  exists ( select 1 from cte t2
  where t1.id=t2.id  
  having count(distinct country)=2
 )
 and country in ('France','Italy')
```

output

```
id
B
C
```

[demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e453427395a2f064f4b142919deda08)

Comment: This is not correct. For example, remove the last record/union in the cte and you will get an incorrect result. Right now you code would return "only Italy **or** France", but should return "only Italy **and** France"

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach in Postgres is to use array for the comparison:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having array_agg(country order by country) = array['France', 'Italy'];
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f8a2305202a8c71840e8478ce04125d7) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this

```
select distinct(id) 
        from countries
        where country in ('Italy','France');
```